# How to use vanilla script to bounce elements from each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, collision

I've tried adding the top and left changes, and margin (with different positioning changes too) changes to each element if one approaches another but only the margin change works once.  Is there a way to make them work more consistently?

This is where I've used a function to add the event listeners:

```
var three = document.getElementById('three');
var test = document.getElementById('test');
var two = document.getElementById('two');
var obj = null;

function testmovea(object, event) {
    obj = document.getElementById(object.id);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", move);
}

function move(event) {
    obj.innerText = event.clientX + ' ' + event.clientY;
    obj.style.position = 'absolute';
    obj.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
    obj.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
    three.addEventListener('mouseover', borders);
    three.addEventListener('mouseleave', bordersOff);
    two.addEventListener('mouseenter', bTwo);
    test.addEventListener('mouseenter', bTest);
    two.addEventListener('mouseleave', bTwoReset);
    test.addEventListener('mouseleave', bTestReset);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopMove);
}
```

```js
    function bTwo() {
        two.style.margin = "10%";
    }
    
    function bTwoReset() {
        two.style.margin = "0%";

    }
    
    function bTest() {
        test.style.margin = "10%";
    }
    
    function bTestReset() {
        test.style.margin = "0%"
    }
```

This is the mouse stop event I use:

```js
    function stopMove() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', move);
        test.removeEventListener('mouseover', bTest);
        two.removeEventListener('mouseover', bTwo);
        test.removeEventListener('mouseleave', bTestReset);
        two.removeEventListener('mouseleave', bTwoReset);
    }
```

the `testmovea` function relies on a `onmousedown` property defined for a DOM element of the page

Update:
I've managed to get it to partially work:

```
 function collide(el1, el2) {
    if(twoBoundX >= threeBoundY || threeBoundY >= twoBoundX) {
        two.style.margin = + event.clientX + "px";
        two.style.margin = + event.clientY + "px";
    }
 }
```

where twoBoundX and threeBoundY are getBoundingClientRect() of the respective elements

Here's the full code snippet:

```html
<html>
    <head>

    <style type="text/css">
    #two {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 1%;
        margin: 1%;
        margin-top: 10%;
        width: 10%;
    }
    #three {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 1%;
        margin-top: 2%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="two" onmousedown="testmovea(this, event)" onclick="currentTwoPos()">
    stop movement 
    </div>
    <div id="three" onmousedown="testmovea(this)">Expand div</div>
    <div style="height: 30%" id="two" contenteditable="true">
    some contenteditable</div>
    </body>
        <script>
 var three = document.getElementById('three');
 var two = document.getElementById('two');
 const twoBound = two.getBoundingClientRect();
 const threeBound = three.getBoundingClientRect();
 var threeBoundX = threeBound.x;
 var threeBoundY = threeBound.y;
 var twoBoundX = twoBound.x;
 var twoBoundY = twoBound.y;
 var twoBoundBottom = null;
 var twoBoundTop = null;
 var obj = null;
 
  function collide(el1, el2) {
    if(twoBoundX >= threeBoundY || threeBoundY >= twoBoundX) {
        two.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
        two.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
        three.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
        three.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
    }
 }
 
    function testmovea(object, event) {
    obj = document.getElementById(object.id);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", move);
    }
  
function move(event) {
    obj.innerText = event.clientX + ' ' + event.clientY;
    obj.style.position = 'absolute';
    obj.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
    obj.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
    two.addEventListener('mouseover', collide);
    three.addEventListener('mouseover', collide);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopMove);
} 

    function stopMove() {
    mousemove = false;
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', move);
        three.removeEventListener('mouseover', collide);
        two.removeEventListener('mouseover', collide);
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: in order for top and left to work, your element must be [positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: did you set position property to your `two` element?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried different positions and on both margin and left/top changes too which only work once.  I want the elements to not be able to enter each other's boundaries.

Comment: margin property won't work on some position properties like `position: absolute`.

Comment: @Layhout I've tried all types and it only bounces once

Comment: Your events are not chained. It may work but you can't see due to asynchronous job in javascript. Could you create snippet with all your workspace such as html, and css? It can be better to see what is wrong.

Comment: It is hard to even give any advice on this since we don't know how and when these listeners were added or what the referenced elements are. It would be great to see an MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Create two elements. Position them absolutely so you have precise control over their location on the page. Use [`getClientBouningRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to determine the precise location of the edges of the element. Use `requestAnimationFrame` to animate the movement of the elements. On each tick, calculate the new position and velocity of each element and check for a collision using a simple collision algorithm checking whether the boundary of one is inside the other. If there is a collision, update element velocities & continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## collision detection

You need to define a `function` that checks whether two of your shapes collide. If you only have rectangles whose vertex are parallel with the OX and OY vertexes, it would look like this:

```
function areColliding(r1, r2) {
    return !(
           (r1.x > r2.x + r2.w) ||
           (r1.x + r1.w < r2.x) ||
           (r1.y > r2.y + r2.h) ||
           (r1.y + r1.h < r2.y)
           );
}
```

Of course, if some rotation or even other shapes are involved into your problem, then you need to extend/adjust the collision detector accordingly.

## a shared function

You need to create a `function` that would receive the current status of the elements and the move that happens. It would look like this:

```
function handleMove(currentPositions, proposedPositions) {
    while (!validPositions(proposedPositions)) {
        proposedPositions = generateNewPositions(currentPositions, handleCollisions(proposedPositions));
    }
    refreshUI(proposedPositions);
}
```

- `currentPositions` is the set of positions your elements currently have
- `proposedPositions` is the set of positions your elements are going to have if there are no collisions
- `validPositions` checks for any pair of shapes that would collide and returns true if none of those pair collide and false if at least one such pair collides
- `proposedPositions` is being refreshed `while` there are still collisions
- `generateNewPositions` is your handler for collision-based changes
- `handleCollisions` effectuates changes to avoid collision
- `refreshUI` refreshes the UI

## event handling

your mouse events should handle change updates by loading all the positions of your elements and calling this shared functionality.

Note: If you have further problems, then you might need to create a reproducible example so we could see your exact structure, styling and code as well.

```html
<html>
    <head>

    <style type="text/css">
    #two {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 10%;
        padding: 1%;
        margin: 1%;
        margin-top: 10%;
    }
    #three {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 1%;
        margin-top: 2%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="two" onmousedown="testmovea(this, event)" style="position: relative;">
    stop movement 
    </div>
    <div id="three" onmousedown="testmovea(this)" style="position: relative;">Expand div</div>
    <!--<div style="height: 30%; position: relative;" id="two" contenteditable="true">
    some contenteditable</div>-->
    </body>
        <script>
 var three = document.getElementById('three');
 var two = document.getElementById('two');
 let moveStarted = false;
 
  function collide() {
    const first = two.getBoundingClientRect();
    const second = three.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (!(
        (first.x + first.width < second.x) ||
        (second.x + second.width < first.x) ||
        (first.y + first.height < second.y) ||
        (second.y + second.height < first.y)
    )) {
        two.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
        two.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
        three.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
        three.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
    }
 }
 
    function testmovea(object, event) {
    obj = document.getElementById(object.id);
    if (!moveStarted) {
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", move);
        moveStarted = true;
    }
    }
  
function move(event) {
    //obj.innerText = event.clientX + ' ' + event.clientY;
    obj.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
    obj.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
    if (!obj.classList.contains("dragged")) obj.classList.add("dragged");
    collide(obj);
} 

    function stopMove() {
    mousemove = false;
    if (moveStarted) {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', move);
        moveStarted = false;
    }
    }
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopMove);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you break this answer down further into more detail with an example please? Thank you!

Comment: @user784446 I would be happy to do so, but can you create a snippet/fiddle and add that to your answer? It would be great to start resolving this based on a reproducible ready-made example that you would provide. Thanks!

Comment: I've added an updated code snippet which you can run

Comment: @user784446 excellent, now I can see the behavior we are discussing. My understanding is that you want to be able to move the rectangles , but, if the cursor gets into another rectangle (an overlap happens), then prevent that from happening. Can you explain how the exact prevention should work? A possible solution would be to avoid moving the dragged rectangle while it would overlap anything. Another possible solution is to still move it, but in a different manner. The `collide` function does not look to be correct, because 1. its logical validation does not cover all cases and

Comment: @user784446 2. the variables used in the `if` are never updated, at least I do not see them being updated. So, this validation needs to be fixed and the handler for invalid cases also needs to be fixed. We can of course achieve that, but I need some extra info about the intention of what should happen when an overlap occurs and how should that be handled, as well as I need to know how should we proceed when leave all rectangles with the mouse so we would have no more overlapping?

Comment: could you show me an example of how I could get either the two or three div to repel from each other from any direction with just using vanilla JS? Thanks

Comment: @user784446 I'm not sure what the exact goal is, but I have added a snippet that does some collision detection and adjustment.